# how can I get a table OR list that contain all students mark of a course?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

My tables are these:

> **edu_submark**: Id, sm_mark, sub_lesson_id, st_id, course_id
>
> **edu_mark**: Id, ma_mark, ma_midterm, st_id, course_id
>
> **edu_sub_lesson**: Id, sl_title, sl_hour, lesson_id
>
> **edu_lesson**: Id, le_title,department_id
>
> **edu_course**: Id,co_title
>
> **edu_student**: Id, ac_fname, ac_lname

I want this result:

```
Jack:
active directoy 99
win7            84
winServer       45


Joe:
active directoy 76
win7            NULL
winServer       64

.
.
.
```

I used this PROCEDURE, but it returns only one student marks:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[st_select_mark]
    @st_id int ,
    @course_id int
AS
    declare @lesson_id int
    set @lesson_id=(SELECT lesson_id FROM edu_course WHERE Id=@course_id)

SELECT 
    a.sl_title,a.lesson_id,a.Id,b.sm_mark
FROM  
    edu_sublesson a 
LEFT JOIN
    edu_submark b on a.Id = b.sub_lesson_id AND b.course_id = @course_id AND b.st_id = @st_id
WHERE
    a.lesson_id = @lesson_id

    SELECT ma_mark,ma_midterm FROM edu_mark WHERE st_id=@st_id AND course_id=@course_id
RETURN 0
```

Comment: You have two selects  which return 7 columns in your stored procedure but your desired output has 3 columns. Can you explain why you are using those two selects? Can you add column names to your output as well

Comment: I used two select to get two tables.first table is students sub_marks and second table is for midterm and total mark

Comment: Why desired output has only 3 columns then?

Comment: the columns count are variable,can be 3 or more .these are sub_lessons

Comment: You need to add sample data in the tables and the corresponding output for me to understand what you want